# MySQL - Slow query - wp_options table. Website unable to handle traffic

Tags: mysql, database, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After spending several days researching, I have placed a website on a c1.medium instance, Amazon Linux, and the MySQL database on a db.m1.medium instance.  The RDS is running MySQL version 5.6.13.  I have allocated 100 GB for the DB instance and have set the provided IOPS at 1,000.  The website is photo based, permits user uploads and at peak hours has 400+ visitors.

Once I enabled the slow query logging I found the issue appears to be with the wp_options table, which when looking into phpmyadmin I found contains information on the WordPress plug-ins and theme.  Ex:

SET timestamp=1390186963;

SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes';

Time: 140120  3:04:17

User@Host: xxxx Id:   744

Query_time: 49.248039  Lock_time: 0.000180 Rows_sent: 485  Rows_examined: 538

After experimenting with a few of the DB parameters I set the query_cache_type to 1 and the query_cache_size to 64MB.  I was hoping that enabling the caching would stop the database from repeatedly calling the wp_options table, but that unfortunately doesn’t appear to be the case.  Any suggestions?  What would be the next steps to take to figure out the cause of this issue?  When looking at the CloudWatch metrics the hardware appears to be sufficient, but maybe not?

Below are screenshots of the CloudWatch metrics for both instances.

EC2:
[image: EC2]

RDS:
[image: RDS]

Answer (score 2):

Unless

```
Query_time: 49.248039 Lock_time: 0.000180 Rows_sent: 485 Rows_examined: 538
```

is a copy/paste error, something is very very wrong here. That's 50 seconds to select 485 rows out of 538! The only reason for this, that i can imagine, is you have some EXTREMELY long columns in option_value, which is a longtext. Try

```
SELECT option_name, length(option_value) FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes';
```

to check if something went wrong here, like (as you say it's a photo website) an image, or a video file, that would have to have a size of at least a a few dozen gigabytes to produce your effect, sneaking into the theme configuration.

If you can, mysqldump() your database, import the dump into a local database, and try the same select on your local copy. This might help in deciding if it's a problem with the data, or some artificial limit on your Amazon instance that's set too low.

Comment: Unfortunately, the 50 seconds for that query is not a copy / paste error!  I ran the query you suggested.  Below are option_name variables that possess the five longest LENGTH(option_value) although there are 25 that have a length over 1,000.
1) NSX_LogToEmail - 939796
2) 301_redirects – 47972
3) Of_template – 12486
4) Rewrite_rules – 11562
5) Gd-star-rating-gfx – 10088

Do you believe this is the source of the problem?

Comment: I would have expected something larger, that gets read often. However, the NSX_LogToEmail seems fishy to me as well. Googling that finds some source code that belongs to a facebook/twitter auto poster plugin for wordpress - this option collects error messages from that plugin, and every new error message reads this string, appends to it, and writes it back. Maybe this causes a lot of I/O on the database. Check the option value - maybe the log messages will give you a hint what goes wrong.

Comment: Or try clearing the option value - if your performance gets better for a while, then decreases again as the option value fills up, you have found your culprit.

Comment: What is the size of your RDS instance?

Comment: @datasage RDS is on a db.m1.medium instance.

Comment: @panoramic that instance size should not be causing what you are seeing. Looking closely at your stats, it may actually be something else that is the cause of the problem. You appear to have a huge spike of incoming traffic, causing swap usage. Do you have any caching set up for wordpress?

Comment: @datasage With the exception of setting the query_cache_type to 1 and the query_cache_size to 64MB, I have no done nothing with caching. What catching plug-in would you suggest?

Comment: @panoramic That can get kind of detailed, but if you can bring your memory usage down in a spike like this you should be able to survive it. I'll post an answer with suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a spike of incoming traffic large enough to create a significant number of server threads. These threads take up so much memory that the instance is pushed to using swap which slows everything to a crawl.

1. Use FCGI configuration for PHP. If you are using mod_php, every Apache thread loads with mod_php. Even if the thread is not serving a request that requires php processing.
2. Install APC if you have not already. This will cache php bytecode and speed up requests.
3. Install W3 total cache. Configure it to use memory caching with memcached. You will likely need to install memcached and a php memcached extension.
4. If the above isn't enough, set up varnish and/or pass your site through cloudfront or cloudflare.